# Merge-sort using a merge function that has 2 arrays as parameters

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, merge, mergesort

```
void Merge1(int v1[], int L1, int v2[], int L2) // L1 and L2 are the lenghts of the vector
{
    int v3[100],i,j, a1,a2;
    a1=a2=0;
    for (i = 0; i < L1 + L2; i++)
    {
        if(a1!=L1 && a2 !=L2)
        {
            if (v1[a1] < v2[a2])
            {
                v3[i] = v1[a1];
                a1++;
            }
            else
            {
                v3[i] = v2[a2];
                a2++;
            }
        }
        else if (a1==L1)
        {
             v3[i] = v2[a2];
                a2++;
        }
        else if (a2==L2)
        {
            v3[i] = v1[a1];
            a1++;
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < L1+L2; i++)
    {
        v1[i]=v3[i];
    }
}
```

This is my Merge function using 2 arrays. It seems to work fine.

```
void MergeSort (int v[], int l, int r)
{
    if (l==r) return;
    int m = (l+r)/2;
    MergeSort (v, l, m);
    MergeSort (v, m+1, r);
    Merge1(v, m, v+m, r-m);
}
```

In `int main ()`, I use `MergeSort(v,0,n-1)`, and for an array like:

> 9 5 2 9 4 6 4 3 8 1 22 11 7 1

the result is

> 1 2 3 4 4 6 7 8 9 9 5 11 22 1

For an array like:

> 1 7 3 2 6 2 4 21 1 2

the result is

> 1 1 2 2 4 6 7 3 21 2

I don't get it. It seems to work just a little. I know that normally, MergeSort is used with a Merge function that has only one vector as parameter ( `Merge2 (int v[], int left, int m, int right)` ), and if you replace my line `Merge1(v, m, v+m, r-m)` with `Merge2(v, l, m, r)`, my MergeSort function would work. Although I want to use my function `Merge1` or a function that has 2 arrays as parameters and their lenghts.

Comment: Why don't you use a debugger?

Comment: I used the debug for programs that weren't working. This program is recursive, it is working, so I don't know how to debug. The logic of the program is wrong and I can't see why.

Comment: "...it is working," - i beg to differ. Debugger's aren't just for finding crashes.

Comment: If it is working, what are you asking? From your output it doesn't seem to be working at all.

Comment: It has no errors, this is what I meant.

Comment: It's not giving the output which it should; that means that it has a bug, which means you should use a debugger.

Comment: Okay, but I don't know how to do that for recursive functions that have no errors.

Comment: I'm going to leave one more comment, then turn in. There are several things wrong, but look carefully at what you're passing as the *base* address to your `Merge1` function for the first parameter, and its length. You need to think about whether that is correct (it isn't).

Comment: Yes, I believe you're right. I think I should modify the first argument into v+l. It still doesn't work properly, but I'll keep trying

Comment: I modified the parameters from Merge1(v, m, v+m, r-m) into Merge1(v+l, (r-l)/2, v+(l+r)/2, (r-l)/2); v+l is the starting point for the "first" array. (r-l)/2 is the length of the array (the half lenght of the total array). The starting point for the "second" array should be therefore v+l+(r-l)/2 which is v+(l+r)/2. The length of the "second" array should be the same, (r-l)/2. It seems pretty logical to me, but it still doesn't work properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice the Merge1 function call `Merge1(v, m, v+m, r-m);`, and refer to the function declaration:

```
void MergeSort (int v[], int l, int r)
{
    if (l==r) return;
    int m = (l+r)/2;
    MergeSort (v, l, m);
    MergeSort (v, m+1, r);
    Merge1(v, m, v+m, r-m);
}


void Merge1(int v1[], int L1, int v2[], int L2) // L1 and L2 are the lenghts of the vector
```

As the intended parameter L1 and L2 to be `the length of the vector`, the left part ranges from `index l to index m`, so the length of the left part is `m-l+1`, the right part ranges from `index m+1 to index r`, so the length of the right part is `r-m`.

To sum up, the implementation of Merge1 function is ok, but the function call should be `Merge1(v+l, m-l+1, v+m+1, r-m);`. So the `MergeSort` function should be：

```
void MergeSort (int v[], int l, int r)
{
    if (l==r) return;
    int m = (l+r)/2;
    MergeSort (v, l, m);
    MergeSort (v, m+1, r);
    Merge1(v+l, m-l+1, v+m+1, r-m);
}
```

The revised code has been tested ok on my computer, see if it works for you on your data.

Comment: It is working, it is logical, you explained well, I find no error whatsoever. Thank you!!